# How can I silently run a remote PowerShell command without having to hard code my password?

Tags: powershell, credentials

I am trying to run:

```
Invoke-Command -Computer $computer -ScriptBlock {...}
```

But I get the error "Access is denied" winrm error and I am hesitant to use the following:

```
Invoke-Command -Computer $computer -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {...}
```

where $cred is:

```
$username = "John Doe"
$password = "ABCDEF"
$secstr = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.SecureString
$password.ToCharArray() | ForEach-Object {$secstr.AppendChar($_)}
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -
argumentlist $username, $secstr
```

It has to be run remotely and it must be silent. So I can't have the PSCredential pop up window mid script.

Can someone please show me or point me to a document that will lead me to a possible solution?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does anyone else intend to use this script besides you?

Comment: Just me but others can view it.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician's solution will work for you, but the encrypted password is limited to only your user account on the machine that you create it on.  I'd suggest creating a registry key rather than a file for something of this nature as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing that you can do is encrypt the password and save it to disk. Then you can read that file, and convert the encrypted password to a secure string and make a credential object from that. Mind you, this must be done with the account that will be used to run the script.

```
'$uper$secret1' | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Set-Content .\AccountPass.txt
```

That will save your password to disk in a text file. If you open the text file it will look something like:

```
01000000d08c9ddf0115d1118c7a00c04fc297eb01000000b584d55e9c47c942904dd30531d3ad070000000002000000000003660000c0000000100000003060266c3c4333a41e7f0e92176fb3d50000000004800000a000000010000000a2c8bbb2a3666c092004bb5e66fd440320000000636a413a6905789e0f3521cea3d8703405897cd5948da955192bcccd08990ffc1400000068c1
```

5f8ac088ef0972dfce7d5a20ff3bbcdac4cc
Now, the account that created the file will be the only one that can decrypt it, but that account can then run:

```
$Password = Get-Content .\AccountPass.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString
$Creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("$env:UserDomain\$env:UserName",$Password)
```

Now you have a credential object, without having to save a password in plaintext. As mentioned, the only account that can decrypt the password in the text file is the one that generated the text file, and the text file will have to be updated whenever the password is changed.

Comment: It's also limited to machine if you're relying purely on DPAPI.

Comment: So if I were run this script on tons of machines, I would have to store the password on each machine?

Comment: @Ben Correct.  DPAPI relies on current user account and machine thumbprint (in the easiest terms) which is what the `ConvertTo-SecureString` implementation relies on.

Comment: Yes, you would. You are really looking to silently run a script on several machines that have to remotely execute commands that require credentials? Maybe you should setup a scheduled task on the remote machine that runs under the creds you need, and have the 'tons of machines' remotely execute that task.

Comment: So this is the equivalent of generating a key pair for Linux machines?

Comment: @Ben Why are you trying to put the script locally when you're using `Invoke-Command`?